# Yahoo api call returns 505 error

Tags: php, curl, yahoo-api, http-status-code-505

```
var value = 'New Delhi, India';

 $yql_query_url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from geo.places where text='.value.'&format=json';
$ch = curl_init($yql_query_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);  //Returns the headers

$json = curl_exec($ch); //RESULT  of YQL QUERY

$status_code = array(); 
    preg_match('/\d\d\d/', $json, $status_code); 

    switch( $status_code[0] ) {
       case 200:
       echo "HTTP status of 200: Success!";
       // Success
       break;
       case 503:
       die('Your call to Yahoo Web Services failed and returned an HTTP status of 503. That means: Service unavailable. An internal problem 
            prevented us from returning data to you.');
       break;
       case 403:
       die('Your call to Yahoo Web Services failed and returned an HTTP status of 403. That means: Forbidden. You do not have permission to access          this resource, or are over your rate limit.');
       break;
       case 400:
       die('Your call to Yahoo Web Services failed and returned an HTTP status of 400. That means:  Bad request. The parameters passed to the                   service did not match as expected. The exact error is returned in the XML response.');
       break;
       case 401:
       die('Your call to Yahoo Web Services failed and returned an HTTP status of 401. That means:  Authorization Required. The parameters passed           to the service did not match as expected. The exact error is returned in the XML response.');
       break;

       case 999:
       die('Your call to Yahoo Web Services failed and returned an HTTP status of 999. That means:  Unable to process this request at this time.                The parameters passed to the service did not match as expected. The exact error is returned in the XML response.');
       break;
       default:
       die('Your call to Yahoo Web Services returned an unexpected HTTP status of:' . $status_code[0]);
    }
     preg_match('/{.*}/',$response, $json);
     $result=json_decode($json,true);
```

I am getting the error `Your call to Yahoo Web Services returned an unexpected HTTP status of:505`

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Wiki:

> 505 HTTP Version Not Supported
>   The server does not support the HTTP protocol version used in the request.

You can force the HTTP version when using curl:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_NONE);//CURL will choose
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);//Use 1.0
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);//Use 1.1
```

Choosing one of 1.0 or 1.1 should resolve your problem.

Edit:

Also just noticed your query string:

> http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from geo.places where text='.value.'&format=json

This is not valid. You'll want to `url_encode` the query. You are also using javascript syntax instead of PHP:

```
$value = 'New Delhi, India';

$query = "select * from geo.places where text='$value'";
$yql_query_url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q='.urlencode($query). '&format=json';
```